# OBSOLETE - Official Stack Overflow iOS App

Tags: app, obsolete, ios

### Screenshots

[image: Screenshot of Question List] [image: Screenshot of Question] [image: Screenshot of Question Editor]

### About

Stack Overflow is the can’t-code-without-it site where professional and enthusiast programmers ask their toughest questions and get answers from their peers. Learn, share and level up — on the go — with the Stack Overflow official app.

- **Read, ask, answer, comment, flag and vote** on questions.
- **Get a push notification** when someone answers or comments on your question. Anything that would trigger a Stack Overflow inbox message triggers an app notification. As always, you can easily turn notifications on and off via settings.
- **Search and filter** by active, newest, votes and more.
- **Draft questions on the go**, even when you’re offline. Markdown tools make it easy to add images and code blocks.
- **Get back to good questions** with a browsing-history view that lists questions you’ve recently looked at.

### Download

[Download from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1155618808?pt=1160989&ct=Stack%20Apps&mt=8)

### How this relates to the Stack Exchange app

[From the launch announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/):

> For now, the two apps have nearly identical functionality.
>
> The new Stack Overflow app has one key difference: It only contains Stack Overflow questions and answers. The existing Stack Exchange app covers our network of more than 170 communities — including Stack Overflow. So, if you are a power user who actively participates in multiple Stack Exchange sites, you may want to keep it on your phone to continue seeing all of your Q&A in one place.
>
> If you decide to download both apps, your notifications will be split between the two. Your Stack Overflow notifications will appear in the Stack Overflow app, and all other Stack Exchange notifications will appear in the Stack Exchange app.

Comment: So, can we expect API version 2.3 (or 3.0)?  To support these new features?

Comment: This is exciting! :D

Comment: So *that’s* what [the original app designers were hired back for](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4913051#4913051)!

Comment: @BrockAdams There's no timeline yet for new features (and API backing them), just focussed getting the app working.  Still, there are some smaller changes like submitting suggested edits, tag preferences, and `can_` fields ready for 2.3 when I get the app shipped.

Comment: Please, no. Keep it in one app.

Comment: @Brian was the app renamed from iOS app to iPhone app? Those are different things, as there are many devices which are not iPhone which run under iOS.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It was just going to be iPhone initially, but now it's going to be iOS without much special treatment on iPad.  Updated.

Comment: Thanks @Brian. But due to the big difference in screen size between the devices, won't the lack of treatment cause lots of layout/design issues?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Guess I should rephrase.  The app will still have some key features from SE.app.  Split list and item view in landscape, live question preview, but it isn't getting special UI treatment in the way of having it's own special navigation compared to iPhone and it won't have its own custom user profile view.  Some views will definitely be sparse or overly spread out compared to their iPhone counterparts, but probably not much more so than in the SE app.

Comment: Did this app get taken down by Apple just like Google took down the Android version or did you decide to discontinue it?

Comment: Has anybody an info why the app is currently not available in IOS store?

Comment: It’s not available on app store anymore