# Stack Overflow Android App (Placeholder)

Tags: app, placeholder

This is a placeholder for the Stack Overflow Android app.

Parallel to the [Stack Overflow iOS App](https://stackapps.com/questions/7176/stack-overflow-iphone-app-placeholder), these are Stack Overflow only versions of the Stack Exchange apps.

More information to come soon.

Comment: Just to get it straight: you abandoned the existing android app and stopped fixing its bugs or adding new feature, in favor of building a whole new app from scratch, just for Stack Overflow? Sorry, but I do not like this decision.

Comment: Stackoverflow is sitting on windows server, written in C# .net, how can you not have a Stack overflow windows phone app! </trollololo>

Comment: @Shadow they have surely predicted your reaction. What are their reasons, and why don't you like it?

Comment: @Ooker turns out it was desperate attempt to bring more users to download the app. It failed though, mobile app team does not exist anymore. (Both Kasra and Brian are now "just" ordinary SE developers, working on bugs and features not related to the app.)

Comment: @Shadow not exist anymore? Any official announcement? Does that mean reporting bugs are useless now? And I still don't understand why they did it at the first place

Comment: @Ooker [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/152859): "but Brian and I are both slated to be full time on the DAG team for the foreseeable future". As for why, because without enough downloads, it's not worth the money they spend on developing it. And yes, reporting new bugs or asking for new features is pointless.