# Please "release" and/or document API version 2.3

Tags: feature-request, api, documentation, api-v2.3

I was playing around a bit with [Fiddler](https://www.internetrix.com.au/blog/how-to-debug-ios-andriod-apps-https-traffic/) to capture traffic from the Stack Exchange iOS app. To my surprise, it uses version 2.3 of the Stack Exchange API:

[image]

I noticed [here](https://stackapps.com/a/7358/34061) that it has some extra functions compared to the current release (v2.2), and that it wasn't documented yet. However, that answer is one-and-a-half year old; any updates on this topic? Or will this keep on being an unofficial release, only released to support some additional features for the mobile app, which as we know [isn't actively developed anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/295232)?

Comment: [This is now status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366977)

Comment: @double-beep [my answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366980/295232) got a [status-review], so I'm waiting for an official response here. Not all 2.3 API methods have been documented, it seems.

Comment: Your answer finally got a [status-completed] :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that [version 2.3 has been around since at least Aug 28, 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264399/148310) <sup><sub>(Date of that answer)</sub></sup>.

I could have sworn that one of the SE guys said they weren't going to document it, but can't find a reference for that.

Anyway, [in Jan 2017 the (former) API developer, Brian Nickel, said](https://stackapps.com/questions/7176/official-stack-overflow-ios-app#comment15435_7176):

> There's no timeline yet for new features (and API backing them), just focused getting the app working. Still, there are some smaller changes like submitting suggested edits, tag preferences, and can_ fields ready for (API) 2.3 when I get the app shipped.

Given that that was before API devs got switched to ["Developer Affinity & Growth" (DAG)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth), per [the answer you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/148310), it may be a while before we can see anything official on the next API release...