# API to submit a Suggested Edit

Tags: support, feature-request, api, editing

Is there a way of using the API to submit a suggested edit?

This would allow users without the [edit privilege](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/edit) to at least submit their suggestion.

There is no create/add endpoint listed in the [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) under Suggested Edits.

When using the [edit question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question) endpoint with a user without the edit privilege, the following error is returned:

```
{
  "error_id": 407,
  "error_message": "Account is not allowed to suggest edits",
  "error_name": "write_failed"
}
```

Which looks like an error when a user receives a [suggested edit ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140936/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits?noredirect=1&lq=1), but suggesting the edit works when using the website instead of the API, so I'm assuming there is no penalty associated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is not available in the official released version of the API (2.2), but since the Stack Exchange apps (now discontinued) do have this functionality, it must exist, right? Indeed, it's part of the [undocumented 2.3 version of the API](https://stackapps.com/q/8149/34061).

Somebody asked the same question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Stack Exchange API returning 407: Account is not allowed to suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323797/295232). More details to be found there, but the good news is that you only have to change the endpoint (provided your current implementation works for regular edits):

- replace `/2.2/questions/{id}/edit` with `/2.3/questions/{id}/suggested-edit/add`
- replace `/2.2/answers/{id}/edit` with `/2.3/answers/{id}/suggested-edit/add`