# Improve error message when attempting to edit a post while not having enough reputation

Tags: feature-request, api, editing

When attempting to [edit a post](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-answer) while not having [enough reputation](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/edit), like happened here: [API to submit a Suggested Edit](https://stackapps.com/q/8668/34061), the API returns the following:

```
{
  "error_id": 407,
  "error_message": "Account is not allowed to suggest edits",
  "error_name": "write_failed"
}
```

Today I was tricked into believing that it couldn't submit a *suggested* edit, like [this case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140370/295232) (not sure if that wording is still used).

It would be a lot clearer if the error message were changed to

> Account is not allowed to make edits