# How are API changes announced?

Tags: support, api

How are API changes announced? Are emails sent out to developers, or is there someplace I can subscribe to?

Answer (score 1):

They're not announced via a dedicated channel, perhaps because there haven't been too much changes in *years*. Version 2.2 has been the latest stable release and while there is a newer 2.3 version to support the official mobile apps, [it hasn't been released](https://stackapps.com/q/8149/34061) and probably never will be since the apps are deprecated.

We regularly discuss the API on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as an often-forgotten part when new changes are being rolled out (e.g. the new [close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339714/295232) or the [renaming of favorites to bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347565/295232)) but those are relatively minor changes (sometimes the format doesn't even change). And there's no good way to monitor those changes either.

A year later, 2.3 *has* been released and the company chose [an announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366977/295232) as medium.