# What is the latest version of the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api

What is the latest version of the Stack Exchange API and its release date?
The document which I referred is for v2.3.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) always refers to the latest official version.

At the time of posting, that is version 2.3.

See also:

- [Please "release" and/or document API version 2.3](https://stackapps.com/questions/8149/please-release-and-or-document-api-version-2-3?rq=1)
- [API 2.3 Release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366977/api-2-3-release)